# Conversion X.509 Certificate represented as a HEX string into PEM encoded X.509 certificate

Tags: openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, pem, x509

Is it possible to convert X.509 Certificate represented as a HEX string to the PEM encoded X.509 certificate? (.CER format)

Answer (score 9):

You can try this (I suppose it is DER encoded)
`cat cert.txt | xxd -r -p | openssl x509 -inform DER -out mycert.pem -outform PEM`

it converts it to binary and then pipes it to openssl to convert it to pem

Comment: Should be blank space separators first removed from hex dump? Also, how to convert to .cer if I have source hex dump with .hex extension?

Comment: doesn't matter, works either way. use the command that I've given, just use you .hex file instead of cert.txt.
This should work under Linux/MacOS/Cygwin(Windows)

Comment: I need output format **.cer**, not .pem, so I modified command: `cat cert.hex | xxd -r -p | openssl x509 -inform DER -out mycert.cer -outform DER`  Is it correct?

Comment: DER is binary encoding, PEM is ascii (base64). A cer file can be either. In your question you have written PEM so the command is with PEM. If you input is alread DER there is no need to convert it again with openssl, then `cat cert.hex | xxd -r -p > mycert.cert` will suffice.

Comment: Sorry I haven't specified that I need this for Windows, above commands is for Linux/Unix

Comment: Then install cygwin http://www.cygwin.com/, in order to get the unix tools under windows.

Comment: Cygwin is problematic, I only use Win32 OpenSSL.